# Ansible playbook to install software fails if already present

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-awx

I am using Ansible Automation Platform v4.2.

I have a playbook to install software (see code below). If the software is not present, the playbook will successfully install the software. However, if I run the playbook against hosts which already have the software installed the playbook will fail with the following error:

"msg": "unexpected rc from '<path to .exe>': see rc, stdout, and stderr for more details"

The stdout and stderr contain no information.

The way I understand it is that I should be able to run the software install playbook against all hosts and any that do not have it will get the software installed. Any hosts which have the software will be ignored during the play.

This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:

     - name: Install sofware
       win_package:
         path: \\<path to .exe>>
         product_id: '<<id>>'
         arguments:
           - /install
           - /quiet
           - /norestart
         state: present
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

I am expecting the playbook to run successfully against the hosts even if the software is already present. This is the idempotency functionality I expect using Ansible.

Comment: Added `windows` tag, as I believe it's crucial here

Comment: (Disclaimer: I don't use windows) Have you checked the `product_id` is correct and points to an existing key in your registry ? See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_package_module.html#parameter-product_id

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the product_id was incorrect. When the `state=present` the `win_package` module will confirm that the `product_id` matches the value in the following registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

If it matches then there is no change to be made and the play continues. If it does not match then it failed.

Updated my playbook with the correct `product_id` value and it worked!